Can the 32 names of maa duga be chanted in bengali?
Can an individual chant the 32 names of maa durga in bengali as written in the bengali translation of chandi in geeta -gorakhpress book. Will it give the same effects as the hindi version?

If the mantra or shloka is originally in Sanskrit please chant in Sanskrit, don't translate it. Similarly it it is in some other language, chant in a language in which originally it was written

Actually i am a bengali and i have both the hindi as well as bengali durga saptashati . So which one should be more suitable for me. I have been chanting the 32 names in hindi for a long time but now i have the bengali one so which one will be better?@CracklingCyclone

Originally it is composed in which language?

I donot know @CracklingCyclone.

Isn't the strotram supposed to be chanted in only Sanskrit?
